# How to set WebStorm to run js file with Node.js in right click popup menu

Tags: webstorm

After using Mongo Explorer in WebStorm, the item "Run app.js" on right-click popup menu always run with Mongo.

Is there any way to set it back to use Node.js as executor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems Mongo plugin registers itself as a default runner for `.js` files. Please follow https://github.com/dboissier/mongo4idea/issues/193 for updates.
For now, I can suggest to either disable this plugin or create **Node.js** configuration manually via **Run/Edit configurations...**